# How to keep insects away

Tags: kitchen

I live in a warm country, cockroaches are endemic here, and I do my utmost to keep them out.  However, occasionally one will sneak past my defenses.  Is my kitchen clean?  You bet ya! Have I done enough to stop these invaders, I thought so... But obviously not.  What is the best way to keep these critters from even thinking about coming over for a nibble?

Comment: Just one way: Emigrate. You'll never stop the occasional wandering cockroach. Or any bug, for that matter. They feed on pretty much anything out there. And I really do mean *anything*.

Comment: They have a need for water every day. If using a residual insecticide, block their access to water (plants, window condensation, sinks, floor drains, etc.). Don't poison the water, food or working surfaces. As an experiment, dust their entrance trails with "Cream of Tarter", it's non-poisonous and they may not want to cross it. "Boric acid" may also have the same effect.

Comment: One aspect I would emphasize is keeping them out of your actual food, by keeping your actual food in well-sealed bug (and mouse, hopefully) proof containers. In many cases this may **not** be the packaging it originally came in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had problems with insects, even when I lived in a relatively cool place.  (My apartment was next to the trash chute, and on the day they sprayed for bugs, it would drive them into my place for the better part of a week).

To help prevent long-term visitors, you want to remove sources of food.  A big one is areas of moisture, which start creating small bits of mold that the insects feast on.  Make sure you don't have water dripping below your sink and if you have a shower, leave the curtain and door or window open to let it vent after every shower.

To keep away the random explorers (or to deal with existing problems), I really like glue boards.  They're just a rectangle of cardboard with a really stick substance on one side.  You can either just peel off the protective paper and set them in places the insects typically visit (under sinks, behind toilets, basements, etc), but you can also typically fold them into a tent-like triangle or an open-ended box that you can place on countertops or floors.  (always place them tight up against the walls, so the open sides are accessible)

Glue traps will catch most insects (even flying, if you can get them to land on them.  Some are 'peanut butter scented' as a lure) and mice.

A few bits of warning, though:

1. Make sure you put them where you're not going to step on them.  They will stick to your shoe.  If you're not putting them under tables or such, fold them into a tent.
2. If you have a lot of insects already, it can be pretty disturbing to see how many insects you actually had.  (I put them in my basement to deal with camel crickets, and it was basically filled.  And the insects were still moving, so it pulsed)
3. It's not a very humane trap for mice.  They get stuck and then keep struggling to get unstuck.

Comment: 4. Trapping them before entering may give a false sense of cleanliness. Especially in combination with 1 ("hidden traps"). Keep checking the traps, and keep cleaning.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt : true, but there are cases where presence of bugs are an indicator of the environment (too much bug spray elsewhere) and not the cleanliness of the area they're found in.  So you can have an unclean place without bugs, and a clean place (other than the bugs) with bugs.

Comment: true, the last part of your sentence was the basis of my comment to the OP: One bug does not an unclean kitchen make.

Comment: #Joe..."I've had problems with insects, even when I lived in a relatively cool place. (My apartment was next to the trash chute, and on the day they sprayed for bugs, it would drive them into my place for the better part of a week)."  Ah ha, I think I've found a clue!  Just recently the local authority saw fit to spray all drains etc...  This could be part of the problem that I have, they have come over to me as a safe haven, I will check, re-check and again all cupboards.  Keep up my shoot to kill policy and see what happens - thanks to everyone for their thoughts

Answer (score 5):

I've had this issue for years of living on apartments.

After trying just about every off the shelf product nothing worked.

I found this mixture to be amazing:
Equal parts of the following:

- Boraic or borax powder
- Icing sugar
- All purpose flour

Sprinkle this in all your cupboards and around the house (corners).
Within three days I was roach free.

Since then I change the mixture monthly and have never had a problem with roaches.

The borax is taken to their next and kills them.  The icing sugar and flour lures them to the mixture.

Comment: Sorry auto text. Should read Borax or Boraic powder

Comment: Hello Jodes, and welcome! When you notice a mistake, you can edit your own post, there is a small grey link for that on the left right below the text you wrote. Also, our system supports some formatting like bullet lists - you can see the syntax I used when you click "edit", or you can also use the controls over the text box while in edit mode. Nice answer BTW, sometimes an infestation can really be exterminated, and borax is a good suggestion to try.